# Cómo corregir este error en Unity, C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Hola soy nuevo en unity y en c# el error es que me ha puesto todo del codigo en error con la lini roja debajo y por lo tanto errores en la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me pone en todos los scripts que tengo la linia roja debajo de la variable.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice el error, ya tienes clases definidas con esos nombres bajo el mismo namespace.
Estoy casi seguro de que en tu caso, tienes los scripts duplicados. Como se puede ver en la primera imagen que adjuntas, tienes una carpeta 'scripts' y otra 'scripts 2' dentro de los assets.